# Instagram API not providing more than 100 followers of a user?

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get followers of a users **API using PHP:-**

```
$id= "xxxxxxx";  
$access_token = "xxxxxx";
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$id/followed-by?access_token=$access_token&count=500
```

but this only returns with **100 records max**.I need to get all the followers and export them in a CSV sheet.

Do I need to purchase any premium plan for this or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Read the instagram endpoint [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

Each response sent by Instagram is wrapped on a Envelope, inside of that you will get a "pagination" url that you can use to get the next set of data.

> Sometimes you just can't get enough. For this reason, we've provided a
>   convenient way to access more data in any request for sequential data.
>   Simply call the url in the next_url parameter and we'll respond with
>   the next set of data.

The response for the `followed_by` will return a json like this

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": {
        ...
    },
    "pagination": {
        "next_url": "url for next 100 responses",
        "next_max_id": "13872296"
    }
}
```

Just make another request for `Response->pagination->next_url`

Answer (score 3):

You have use `pagination.next_url` in API response to get more users.

If you just want to export any user's followers to `csv`, you can use [gramfeed](http://blog.gramfeed.com/post/135373066012/how-to-csv-download-instagram-following-or) to browse and download as csv.

For example here is followers for instagram account, when u scroll down you will have an option to download as `.csv`, you can load all users and then download csv:
http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram#followers

[image]

Comment: Thanks @krisrak for sharing this information. I exactly need to implement same functionality as gramfeed. I have done so far as search functionality of a user and get all users listing then click on that user get list of followers but in my case I am getting 100 records only....do I need to run next page url t get next 100 followers ? and how will be the search between followers?

Comment: use `pagination` in API to get next url and so on until there is no pagination in url, then u will have all users

Answer (score 0):

For large accounts, it's really difficult to get a list of all followers because you can only get them 100 followers at a time (as you're finding). Some automated services will get a list of all your followers by requesting them 100 at a time using multiple tokens (https://www.crowdbabble.com/download-all-instagram-followers/).